# How to combine the same stepper with a horizontal style for a computer and a vertical style for mobile?

Tags: material-ui

The issue is that in the horizontal style the content is displayed after the stepper bar while in the vertical style it is displayed between each step, so it won't help if I only change the "orientation" field according to the screen size.